# Unnecessary warning for invalid tokens when calling file_get_contents

Tags: php, facebook, file-get-contents

The following code tries to run `file_get_contents` for a facebook url based on access token:

```
    $access_token=$ret["oauth_token"];
    $fbid=$ret["oauth_uid"];
    $url ="https://api.facebook.com/method/friends.getAppUsers?format=json&access_token=$access_token";
                try {
                    $content = file_get_contents($url);
                    if ($content === false) {
                        $common_friends = array("error_code" => "something");
                    } else {
                        $common_friends = json_decode($content,true);
                    }
                } catch (Exception $ex) {
                    //Who cares
                }
```

All the Facebook settings are correct, the only potential problem is that the access token is no longer valid. In that case I receive the warning of

> file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
>   Name or service not known

How can I upgrade my code, so if the facebook user access token is expired/invalid, `file_get_contents` will not give a warning, but fail gracefully?

EDIT:

```
$content = @file_get_contents($url);
```

still shows the same warning, however, I want to get rid of it. NetBeans also warns me that error control operator is misused. I have modified my code as follows:

```
                try {
                    User::checkFacebookToken();
                    //file_get_contents sends warning message when token does not exist
                    //the problem is already handled, therefore these warnings are not needed
                    //this is why we set scream_enabled to false temporarily
                    ini_set('scream.enabled', false);
                    $content = file_get_contents($url);
                    ini_set('scream.enabled', true);
                    if ($content === false) {
                        $common_friends = array("error_code" => "something");
                    } else {
                        $common_friends = json_decode($content,true);
                    }
                } catch (Exception $ex) {
                    //Who cares
                }
```

I hope that scream.enabled is only temporarily changed to false.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION 1** : ensure that warnings will not be printed on main output
just add '**@**' to '**file_get_contents()**' to suppress warning since you catched the error correctly by :

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
if(@file_get_contents() === FALSE) {
    // handle this error/warning
}
```

**SOLUTION 2** : verify that you have a valid Facebook token before doing your request, Using Facebook API

```
$ch = curl_init();
// you should provide your token
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=52524587821444123");
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$output = json_decode("[" . curl_exec($c) . "]");

 if(is_array($output) && isset($output[0]->error)) {
    print "Error Message : " . $output[0]->error->message . "<br />";
    print "Error Type    : " . $output[0]->error->type    . "<br />";
    print "Error Code    : " . $output[0]->error->code    . "<br />";
 }else {
    // do your job with file_get_contents();
 }
curl_close($c);
```

Comment: Your idea was not quite working for file_get_contents, as I have still received the warning when the facebook user access token was no longer valid. I have changed my code and consequently edited my question. If you can edit your answer with information.

Comment: Is there a way to suppress warnings for file_get_contents? Putting @ there does not change the behavior.

Comment: @LajosArpad try my SOLUTION 2 to test if facebook token is valid, and in this case you can use file_get_contents() without any warning

Answer (score 1):

You could **alternatively** use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) which has better server response handling and you can display the error gracefully.

```
$access_token = 'your_access_token';
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.facebook.com/method/friends.getAppUsers?format=json&access_token=$access_token"); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

$content = curl_exec($curl);
$response = curl_getinfo($curl);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($response);
if(!curl_errno($curl)){ 
    // Server request success, but check the API returned error code
    $content = json_decode($content, true);
    print_r($content);
    echo $content['error_code'];
    echo $content['error_msg'];
}else {
    // Server request failure
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl);
}

curl_close($curl);
```

### [PhpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/102f5908671bc9d3c00f)